# How are you supposed to take sharp curves at speed?

Tags: redout

I just got Redout and it has a very lacking tutorial.

It mentioned that I can strafe with the right stick, and that was the only hint it gave at how to corner well. It didn't say whether strafing left or right during a right turn was better, for example. It didn't say whether I should ease up on the gas, or brake, or anything like that.

What is the intended way to take sharper turns in this game? I can't seem to find a method that doesn't either kill my speed or have me smashing into a wall.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer. Although I'm not consistent at it yet, I have accidentally succeeded a few times.

The best way to take a turn is to take it really wide. This effectively lessens the actual turn radius you're going to need. So, for example, if the upcoming turn is to the left, you want to get all the way to the right side of the roadway well before the turn even starts, and then wind up all the way at the right side of the roadway after the turn is over, but cut all the way to the left side during the turn itself.

Then, shortly before the turn starts (still assuming we're turning left), push the left stick (to steer) to the left, to the point where that input along would probably have you crashing into the inner wall. At the same time, push the right stick (to strafe) to the right, which will compensate for you steering into the wall just enough to barely miss the wall. You'll be sliding kind of sideways through the curve at this point, with the front of your ship facing somewhere half-way between the inside wall and the straightaway after the curve. This will take some practice.

Once you get sufficiently around the curve that you're no longer at risk of hitting the inside wall, then change the direction of your strafe to match the direction of your turn (i.e. push the right stick left in this example) to regain your grip and continue going straight.

tl;dr:

1. Start wide
2. Before the curve, steer towards the curve and strafe away from the curve
3. Somewhere around half-way through the curve, reverse the direction of your strafe

Prepare to smash into the wall a lot as you're learning the timing.

Comment: I've never played the game; but when I read this question the other day I was interested to see the answer (mostly because I just find it interesting to see how different games handle the "driving really fast around corners" mechanic).  This seems like a really awesome way of doing it; I'm glad you were able to figure something out and follow up.